# Random Duplicate error in webconfig

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I declare a random name in the modules section under webserver, and i get a duplicated error messagem:

```
Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'jhgfygsdufygsdufygsdfuy2134567890hergwhegr2'
```

Webconfig Code:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <add name="jhgfygsdufygsdufygsdfuy2134567890hergwhegr2"  />
 </modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Im using WebApi.

Comment: Try adding `<remove name="jhgfygsdufygsdufygsdfuy2134567890hergwhegr2">` first?

Comment: It worked.. I have no ideia why..

Comment: @austinwernli can you make that an official answer? So that i can close the question. Thanks

Comment: I have made it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding `<remove name="jhgfygsdufygsdufygsdfuy2134567890hergwhegr2">` first